# Use KeystoneJS as a blog, but only part of the webapp

Tags: keystonejs

I've got a NodeJS + Angular + MySQL webapp. Is there a way I could use KeystoneJS for blog only?

I am currently serving some pages as static Express pages, and some as an Angular App with UI Router's HTML5 mode enabled.

```
    // Serves static pages generated by Express
    app.use('/staticPage', staticPage);
    app.use('/anotherStaticPage', anotherStaticPage);

    // Serves Angular App
    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/ui/index.html');
    });

    /*
      Need a way to also serve a blog powered by KeystonJS
      It should be accessed at /blog/:postTitle
    */
```

If possible, I prefer to keep my existing set-up and simply add Keystone on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do so.

(1) install keystone, and inside keystones index router, add your two static routers and one app router too.

(2) [Add keystone to existing Express App](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/How-to-Add-Keystone-to-an-Already-Existing-Express-App).

However irrespective of keystoneJS. you have to remove generic handler for angularApp.

```
app.all('/app/*', function(req, res, next) {...});
```

Or else new blog related router has to be added above Angular, as you are doing so far.

Comment: Thanks enRaiser. What if I only need to use Keystone as a blog and it only needs to be accessible at /blog, can I still keep the generic handler for the AngularApp?